# Set timestamp of a file to a custom time

Tags: c, windows

I wanted to change timestamp a file to a custom date, I have find out the following code that must change time stamp a file to the current time but it doesn't work, however. How can I implement a function which it can change timestamp a file to a custom time (specified by user).

```
bool SetFileToCurrentTime(const char* arg_path, const char* arg_file_name)
{
    HANDLE h_File;
    FILETIME ft_FileTime;
    SYSTEMTIME st_SystemTime;

    char l_c_Path[MAX_PATH];

    strcpy(l_c_Path, arg_path);
    strcat(l_c_Path, arg_file_name);

    h_File = CreateFile(l_c_Path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    GetSystemTime(&st_SystemTime);              // Gets the current system time
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st_SystemTime, &ft_FileTime);  // Converts the current system time to file time format

    if (SetFileTime(h_File, (LPFILETIME)NULL, (LPFILETIME)NULL, &ft_FileTime))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: In case you're interested in just doing this (not programming) and you're working on a Linux/UNIX machine, you might use `touch` command for that.

Comment: You could start by reading the docs for [`SetFileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime), or even just stop to think about it for a moment. You're looking to modify the metadata of a file, yet you open it with `GENERIC_READ` access, which does not request the right to modify file attributes. It needs to be opened with `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` access, in which case `FILE_SHARE_READ` is not required and will just be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have find out the following code that must change time stamp a file to the current time but it doesn't work

I don't know what's going wrong, I don't have a Windows compiler to check, but here's some possibilities.

- Check the return value of [`SystemTimeToFileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetofiletime) and [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#return-value).
- Use [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to find out why they failed.
- `l_c_Path` is not putting a path separator between the path and file name. If the caller does not supply one the path will be incorrect. Print out `l_c_Path`.

Rather than using `strcpy` and `strlcat`, consider using [`_makepath_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/makepath-s-wmakepath-s?view=vs-2019) to concatenate paths.

```
char l_c_Path[_MAX_PATH];
errno_t errorCode = _makepath_s(l_c_Path, _MAX_PATH, NULL, arg_path, arg_file_name, NULL);
if( errorCode ) {
  // check the errorCode
}
```

> How can I implement a function which it can change timestamp a file to a custom time (specified by user).

Instead of calling `GetSystemTime` and converting it with `SystemTimeToFileTime`, have the caller pass in a `FILETIME`.